# Using SWRA117D 2.4 GHz antenna on a large board

Tags: antenna, bluetooth, wifi, bluetooth-low-energy, pcb-antenna

[image: The board design image]

I've added the board image. There is one ESP32-C3 on a 2 layer FR-4 board. My question is, how much I'm compromising with the efficiency of the antenna by placing it on a ~52X85mm board considering the ground plane as huge effect on the bandwidth/efficiency of the PCB antenna. Also, If I properly stitch the ground planes (Top and Bottom) edges around the antenna with vias, will that make the antenna efficient? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Stitching ground planes will have little effect at 2.4Ghz, they're already capacitively coupled. you have a via at the ground point of the antenna, that should be enough.

your biggest problem seems the be the 7 pin device above the antenna, surely that's in the keep out zone. The mounting screw below it may also be a problem, but maybe you can use a non-conductive fastener there or tune it out somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, that 7 pin devices is in keep out area, there will be no ground there. Can you also comment on the fact that the board size is 52X85mm and its a 2 layer board and I've read in various papers that the other part of the antenna is the ground plane edge just near the antenna so will the size of the ground plane is any  issue or can work?

Comment: The keep is a keep out, keep all copper and other conductors out.  I'm not an expert on F antennas, my best advice is to follow the advice of the designer of your antenna as closely as you can, if you don't performance will probably suffer.